# Is there an easily implementable alternative to lognormal growth (something with fatter tails)?

Tags: modeling, monte-carlo, distribution

I have a toy model in Excel for the growth of a investment portfolio. I assume iid lognormal annual growth factors:

`=EXP(mu+sigma*NORM.S.INV(RAND()))`

where mu and sigma are calculated to get a given mean and standard deviation right.

I would really like to play around with something that has fatter tails, but with the same mean and standard deviation.

Do you have a suggestion that is easily implementable (in *one* cell)? Can you also point out how to compute its parameters given mean and standard deviation? And, finally, if there is an additional parameter, could you provide a 'reasonable' value for it (annual returns, bunch of asset classes in one portfolio)? That would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by fat tails just fatter tails than the gaussian distribtuion, i.e. a distribution with finite variance, for instance the [Student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) has fatter tails than the normal distribution. If you mean distributions with infinite variance, you have to have a look at [Lévy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_distribution).
In a first attempt you could just substitute the standard normal distribution with Student's t-distribution. Your formular would look like this:

```
=EXP(mu+sigma*T.INV(RAND(),DoF))
```

For degrees of freedom ($\operatorname{DoF}$) you have to specify an integer, preferably $\operatorname{DoF}>2$ so that the variance is finite. For $\operatorname{DoF}\to\infty$ Student's t-distribution converges against the standard normal distribution. The smaller the $\operatorname{DoF}$, the fatter the tails (to the extreme that for $\operatorname{DoF}\leq 2$ the variance does not exist and for $\operatorname{DoF}\leq 1$ the expectation does not exist).

Some words of caution: You can scale Student's t-distribution like you do with the standard normal distribution, but the rescaled parameter $\sigma$ is not the standard deviation. Have a look at the [scaling behaviour of Student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#In_terms_of_scaling_parameter_.CF.83.2C_or_.CF.832). To get the right variance, you have to scale with
$$
\sigma := \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left[X\right]\frac{\operatorname{DoF}-2}{\operatorname{DoF}}}
\textrm{,}
$$
where $\operatorname{Var}\left[X\right]$ denotes the variance of your rescaled Student's t-distribution $X:=\mu+\sigma T$ with $T\sim t\left(\operatorname{DoF}\right)$. The expecated value $\mu$ is the same. Reasonable values for $\operatorname{DoF}$ are $3,\ldots,30$, the smaller the fatter are the tails.

The $\operatorname{exp}$ function in your model transforms instantaneous returns to normal growth factors.

A second word of caution: Normally you would simulate a realisation of a stochastic process which has incemrents distributed like $\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)$. You can add up this log-returns to get to the overall return. With $\operatorname{exp}$ you get back to the value process of your portfolio. This works, because the sum of gaussian random variables stays gaussian. In fact, because of the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) the sum of random variables with finite variance which are not too dependent will converge in distribution to the gaussian distribution. So if you'd replicate the described strategy with Student's t-distributed random variables instead of gaussian random variables and $\operatorname{DoF}>2$ (finite variance), the resulting sum will converge in distribution to a gaussian one and you'd lose the fat tail property of Student's t-distribution.

Comment: I really like this answer - however I have no reputation to spend on upvoting : )